# Set RelativeLayout over RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I want to set RelativeLayout Over RecyclerView. (I have tried with listView also its not working, we don't want Framelayout on top.)

**I Don't want Alternatives, I wanted to understand why its not working logically - its working with other layout, why not with recyclerview.**

**1) XML File (RecyclerVIew)**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

**2) XML File (RelativeLayout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewcenter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgNoDataFound"
        android:src="@drawable/no_data_found" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**3) Java Code**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(com.commonlib.R.layout.no_data_found,  recyclerView);
```

**It's not working - means its not inflating my relative layout over recyclerview.**

**Note : Its not working with ListView also. 
       I don't want to take FrameLayout.**

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly ? Explain properly .

Comment: @tahsinRupam its not inflating my relative layout over recyclerview.

Comment: @ADM i want to set nodata found view over recyclerview. i do not want to use any separate Layout for it just directly inflate over recyclerview

Comment: @Munir First, even if what you want is to inflate a view directly inside a `RecyclerView`, you should understand that this is **not** how you should achieve your desired UI. Second, what makes you say that your call to `inflate()` isn't working? Just because a view has a child does not mean it is required to draw it.

Comment: @BenP. yes, you are right. now I am clear about why it's not inflated. thanks for your answer. all buddies give alternative and code but what I want to know, that's you tell me. really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to inflate the `RelativeLayout` inside the `RecyclerView` here. If you want to inflate above it you must inflate it inside the Recycler's parent, like so:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(com.commonlib.R.layout.no_data_found,  recyclerView.getParent());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below method:

Firstly, Add your `RelativeLayout` in the same xml file which has `RecyclerView` and set it's **visibility** to **gone**.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewcenter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgNoDataFound"
        android:src="@drawable/no_data_found" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you make `RelativeLayout`' **visible** when there is no data. In activity class:

```
if(noData){   //Or list.isEmpty() or something
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

You can still **replace** your `recyclerView` as following;

```
View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) recyclerView.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(recyclerView);
parent.removeView(recyclerView);
View myInflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.no_data_found, parent, false);
parent.addView(myInflatedView, index);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want the reason why its not inflating logically not alternatives, i appreciate your reply.

Comment: If you want to replace `recyclerView`, you can try the above method in my updated answer. But I would prefer the first method as it is much easier. Choice is your's though :)

Comment: bro, can you please check your edited code, first line says recyclerview.getparent(); if you will write 2nd line after the 1st line how could you get recyclerview.

Comment: 2nd - recyclerView = getLayoutInflater() in this method we need recyclerview but you are passing view. - i have to cast that with (RecyclerView)

Comment: after - 5th line application will be crashed, please run the code. 
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.no_data_found, parent, false);

Comment: Extremely sorry, my bad. Please check my latest update. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

For error view you can wrap your relative Layout and errorView inside a relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_fragmentCardStack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/error_view"
    layout="@layout/view_error"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_error.xml can be as .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_errorImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_errorMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Error_Retry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Retry"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

On no data or any connection error make error view visible with proper message.

To add empty view in list view you can use code below.

```
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutId,null);
    listView.setEmptyView(view);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want the reason why its not inflating logically not alternatives, i appreciate your reply.

Comment: Ok so where did you add this view ? I do not see any code for it . You just inflate the view .

Comment: I wan to "Inflate" using viewgroup, check my java code mentioned above.

Comment: There is only two line of java code . i asked how are you adding this view?

Comment: FYI recycler view does not have any setEmptyView feature . So you have to do it above way. ListView does have .

Comment: I have taken listview and setEmptyView its not working.